# JDBC Sqlserver to elastic search : one input to different output?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a sqlserver2016 database that I want to index in elasticsearch using logstash.

Here is my logstash config file which somewhat works :

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "C:\elastic\Microsoft-JDBC-Driver-6.0-for-SQL-Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://10.11.12.13:1433;databaseName=testdb1;integratedSecurity=false;user=ElasticExtractor;password=flyingweisels;"
jdbc_user => "ElasticExtractor"
jdbc_password => "flyingweisels"
statement => "select top 150000 Item_ID itemid,merchant_id merchantid,modelnumber,language_id from items order by Item_Id desc"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "localhost:9200"
index => "testdata"
document_type => "testtype"
document_id => "%{itemid}"
}
}
```

So what this file is supposed to do, as configured is insert 150k items in elasticSearch. Somewhat it only imports about a third of that, such as 62 382 in this case. If I try to insert 50k it only inserts about 20k.
Is there an obvious reason why it would do that ?

Here is the current execution log :

```
[2017-09-01T08:16:31,923][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2017-09-01T08:16:31,927][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,006][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,007][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,042][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,050][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,053][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,219][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,313][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-09-01T08:16:32,643][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.050000s) select top 150000 Item_ID itemid,merchant_id merchantid,modelnumber,language from items order by Item_Id desc
[2017-09-01T08:16:49,805][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Second thing is, let’s say I want to insert a row from SQL server that comes from this input, what plugin can I use so that if the row has a specific “merchant_id” it goes in an elastic TYPE named with that ID. Also, if it has a specific “language” it goes in an elastic INDEX with that language as the name.
Can that be done ?
Should I simply create multiple Logstash config files, one for each of those tasks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong, there were 2 different problems.

## 1. Wrong inserted row count

This was caused by the SQL query I was using. Elastic wants unique `document_id` values and the `left join` I was using caused multiple rows to be returned with the same values. What elastic does in such case is it overwrites the existing row with the new values.

## 2. Assign rows to different indexes and types

I had tried using the same syntax as in the `document_id` which ended up looking like this:

```
index => "%{Language}"
document_type => "%{MerchantID}"
```

This would result in rows getting inserted with in an index called `%{Language}` which was obviously not the desired result.

The problem was simple: ELASTIC DOES NOT LIKE UPPERCASE LETTERS.

So my final configuration file ended up looking like this:

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "C:\elastic\Microsoft-JDBC-Driver-6.0-for-SQL-Server\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://10.11.12.13:1433;databaseName=testdb1;integratedSecurity=false;user=ElasticExtractor;password=flyingweisels;"
jdbc_user => "ElasticExtractor"
jdbc_password => "flyingweisels"
statement => "select top 50000 id itemid,item_id itemid,Merchant_ID merchantid,model,case when (ID%2=0) then 'germanindex' else 'englishindex' end language from items order by id desc"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "localhost:9200"
index => "%{language}"
document_type => "%{merchantid}"
document_id => "%{itemid}"
}
}
```

It works great !